# Gramex does not run after installing via conda

Tags: conda, gramex

The [Gramex installation instructions](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/install/#conda-install) says:

```sh
conda create -y --name gramex python=3.7            # Create a new environment
conda activate gramex                               # Activate it
conda install -y -c conda-forge -c gramener gramex  # Install Gramex
```

But Step 2 (`conda activate gramex`) doesn't work on Linux / Cygwin because of the following error:

`your shell has not been properly configured`

Comment: This is not gramex related.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your shell is not initialized for conda. See https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3371

One way to solve this is to run:

```sh
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
```

This will enable `conda activate`, and you can run `conda activate gramex`.

Comment: conda does not have its own shell. Instead, your shell is not initialized **for** conda

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller -- I reworded "your conda shell is not initialized" to "your shell is not initialized for conda" as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because your shell (I suspect bash) is not initialized for `conda`. This happens in case you did select NO during the installation, when it asked

> Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?

A temporary solution from the anaconda [FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/) (section "Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?") is to run:

```
source <path to conda>/bin/activate
```

if you want a permanent solution, simply do

```
source <path to conda>/bin/activate
conda init bash
```

which will modify your ~/.bashrc to include the shell initialization